# How has this result been obtained??

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, quadratics

We have the quadratic equation

$$ 2y^2 -(1+x)y + x = 0 $$

The author derives the following result from the above equation -

$$ y' = \frac{y-1}{4y-1-x} = \frac{(x-3)y-x+1}{x^2-6x+1} $$

Now, I understand the first part. It has been obtained by simply differentiating w.r.t to $x$ and then solving for $y'$. But, I am unable to obtain the second part.

I have tried lot of different substitutions, but haven't been able to arrive at the result. Please help!!

Comment: I have found this in the following http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/hip.pdf  pg. 7, the author hasn't provided any explanation and I have also tried a lot but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x^2-6x+1)(y-1)-(4y-x-1)((x-3)y-x+1)\\
=-2x^2-4xy^2-4xy+6x+12y^2+2yx^2-6y\\
=(6-2x)(2y^2-(1+x)y+x)\\=0.$$

The identity is valid.

---

To establish it, solve the initial equation for $y$

$$y=\frac{x+1\pm\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}}4$$

and plug in the fraction, to get

$$y'=\frac{x-3\pm\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}}{\pm4\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}}=\frac{\pm(x-3)\sqrt{x^2-6x+1}+x^2-6x+1}{4(x^2-6x+1)}=\frac{4(x-3)y+x^2-6x+1-(x-3)(x+1)}{4(x^2-6x+1)}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your help. The main aim of the author was express the denominator in terms of $x$ only. I get it, that the identity is true. But how did the author arrive at this result?? Like, if I was to remove terms containing $y$ from the denominator, how would i have done that??

Comment: Thanks a lot!! that's exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: @drcp:  in fact, you simply express $y$ as a function of $x$ and plug in the expression !

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to simplify the denominator without explicitly solving for $y$. Note that
\begin{align} 
\big(4y-(1+x)\big)^2 &= 16y^2 - 8(1+x)y + (1+x)^2 \\
&= 8\big(2y^2 - (1+x)y\big) + (1+x)^2 \\
&= -8x + (1+x)^2 \\
&= x^2 - 6x + 1 
\end{align}

Therefore

\begin{align} 
y' = \frac{y-1}{4y-(1+x)} &= \frac{(y-1)\big(4y-(1+x)\big)}{\big(4y-(1+x)\big)^2} \\
&= \frac{4y^2 - 4y - (1+x)y+(1+x)}{x^2-6x+1} \\
&= \frac{2\big(2y^2-(1+x)y\big)+(1+x)y - 4y+ (1+x)}{x^2-6x+1} \\
&= \frac{-2x+(1+x)y-4y+1+x}{x^2-6x+1} \\
&= \frac{1-x+(x-3)y}{x^2-6x+1}
\end{align}